# JS - Input Element Value null before inspecting the element

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a strange case here.

What I'm trying to do is injection of javascript into the page using chrome extension.

That works so far,
Idea is that javascript looks up value of an element and if matches "Hobart" it alerts.

The issue is that value is returning as null, BUT when I inspect the element in chrome, the script starts recognizing the value of the element.

But after page refresh, goes back to null.

The input field element is always displaying "Hobart" on the page.

Its like the page is not allowing reading of the element by javascript if element is not inspected. Any ideas whats going on?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o527N.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDSpa.png)

[Another SS of changing color to red after "enabling" value readout by inspecting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0alA.png)

Javascript And HTML part of the page I'm trying to get value from:

```js
state = document.getElementById("sys_display.incident.assignment_group").value;
if (state=="Hobart") {
document.getElementById("sys_display.incident.assignment_group").style.color="red";
alert("Hobart");

};
```

```html
<div class="input-group ref-container ">

<input id="sys_display.incident.assignment_group" name="sys_display.incident.assignment_group" aria-labelledby="label.incident.assignment_group" 
type="text" 
autocomplete="off" 
autocorrect="off" 
value="Hobart" 
data-type="ac_reference_input" 
data-completer="AJAXReferenceCompleter" 
data-dependent="null" 
data-ref-qual="true" 
data-ref="incident.assignment_group" 
data-ref-key="null" 
data-ref-dynamic="false" 
data-name="assignment_group" 
data-table="sys_user_group" 
class="form-control element_reference_input  " 
style="; " 
spellcheck="false" 
onfocus="if (!this.ac) addLoadEvent(function() {var e = gel('sys_display.incident.assignment_group'); if (!e.ac) new AJAXReferenceCompleter(gel('sys_display.incident.assignment_group'), 'incident.assignment_group', 'null', 'true'); e.ac.onFocus();})" 
aria-required="true">

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using window.setTimeout to call your code after a brief delay? Maybe the element will correctly be accessed then

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath yes, I've had a delay of a minute and still same thing.

Comment: @Barmar none that are related to the page elements or loading of them.

Comment: Literally,after i inspect the element (click on it with inspector) script starts working and i get element value.